# Use dom and sDom options simultaneously

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, datatables

I am implementing a dataTable which has the following features:

1. datatable search box from navbar
2. showing table row status on the top of the table

After long time of experiment on it i am unable to include both features simultaneously in my datatable.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var filterTable =$("#pendingindentdatesort").DataTable({

      "fixedHeader": true,
      "bAutoWidth": false,
      "dom": '<"wrapper"flipt>',
      "sDom": 'ltipr',
      "lengthMenu": [ [-1, 10, 25, 50, 100], ["All", 10, 25, 50, 100] ],
      "bDeferRender": true,
      "aoColumns": [

                          {"bSortable": true},
                          {"bSortable": true},
                          {"bSortable": true},
                          {"bSortable": true},
                          {"bSortable": true},
                          {"bSortable": true},
                          {"bSortable": true},
                          {"bSortable": true},
                          {"bSortable": true},
                          {"iDataSort": 10},
                          {"bVisible": false},
                          {"iDataSort": 12},
                          {"bVisible": false},
                          {"bSortable": true},
                          {"bSortable": true},
                          {"bSortable": true},
                          {"bSortable": true},  
                          {"bSortable": true},
                          {"bSortable": true},
                          {"bSortable": true},
                          {"iDataSort": 21},
                          {"bVisible": false},
                          {"bSortable": true},
                          {"bSortable": true},
                          {"bSortable": true},
                          {"bSortable": true}
      ],
      "order": [[ 10, "desc" ]]                         
   });

   $("#filterbox").keyup(function() {
     filterTable.search(this.value).draw();
   });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use one or the other, they are synonyms. Option `sDom` is the option remained for compatibility with jQuery DataTables 1.9 after jQuery DataTables 1.10 was released and the [new naming convention](https://datatables.net/upgrade/1.10-naming) was introduced.